Android : SSH vpn in kotlin
I need to establish vpn tunnelin using ssh connection in android kotlin. currently i'm able to connect to ssh server using JSch library and forward local port and establish vpn service , but unfortunately i have no access to internet after that. (I tested my ssh connection using another app and it works , so there is nothing with server)
Here is my snippet code :
val jsch = JSch()
       val session: Session = jsch.getSession("test", sshAddress, sshPort)
       session.setPassword(sshPassword)
       session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no")
       session.connect()
       println("jsch connected")
       // Create port forwarding
       val assignedPort: Int =
          session.setPortForwardingL(8180, sshAddress, sshPort)
          println("assignedPort : $assignedPort")

and vpn builder :
val builder: Builder = Builder()
            builder.addAddress("10.0.0.2", 32)
            builder.addRoute("0.0.0.0", 0)
            builder.addDisallowedApplication("com.example.x")
            mInterface = builder.setSession("MyVPN")
                .establish()
            println("vpn established")

            // Create a DatagramChannel to handle VPN packets
            val vpnChannel = DatagramChannel.open()
            vpnChannel.connect(InetSocketAddress(sshAddress, 7300))

            // Allocate buffer for a single packet
            val packet = ByteBuffer.allocate(32767)

            // Get file descriptors for VPN interface
            val vpnInput = FileInputStream(mInterface!!.fileDescriptor)

        // Start forwarding packets

        // Start forwarding packets
            while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                // Read packet from VPN interface
                val length = vpnInput.read(packet.array())
                if (length > 0) {
                    // Set the buffer position to the length of the received packet
                    packet.position(length)

                    // Write packet to SSH tunnel
                    packet.flip() // Prepare the buffer for writing
                    vpnChannel.write(packet)

                    // Clear and reset the buffer for next packet
                    packet.clear()
                } else if (length < 0) {
                    // End of stream reached, break out of the loop
                    break
                }
            }

